# Is it to possible to animate simple line in react native?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, react-native, react-animated

Well, I had high hopes for react-native and thought it was stable when it comes to animation.

So here's the situation:

I have an app that Receives data from an external device. What I'd like to do is visualize the data in line graph format. (**Note:** I'm not looking to use a line graph or any charts. I was hoping to create a line myself like canvas).

The main issue, we cant use CSS animation and CSS keyframes, this makes it hard for the animation of the line.

For example,  suppose this is the data I receive from an external device:

```js
var _data = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0000050048828125, 0.0000137939453125, 0.000049560546875,
  0.00008740234375, 0.00015966796875, 0.000262451171875, 0.0003975830078125, 0.0005687255859375,
  0.0007802734375, 0.001037353515625, 0.0013468017578125, 0.00172119140625, 0.0021756591796875,
  0.0027232666015625, 0.0033880615234375, 0.004206787109375, 0.0052380371093750005,
  0.006586181640625, 0.008400146484375001, 0.010904296875, 0.0144892578125, 0.0196798095703125,
  0.049684204101562504, 0.0886883544921875, 0.11185363769531251, 0.134164306640625,
  0.137352294921875, 0.1160369873046875, 0.08516308593750001, 0.0539765625,
  0.014997436523437501, -0.015882568359375, -0.0387554931640625, -0.06125732421875, -0.0745780029296875, -0.07479357910156251, -0.0725338134765625, -0.0418538818359375,
  0.08582861328125001, 0.397717529296875, 0.8136408691406251, 1.2295617980957032,
  0.9944150390625001, 0.2824605712890625, -0.38949267578125, -0.597251220703125, -0.425675537109375, -0.1537947998046875, -0.0500914306640625, -0.0111041259765625,
  0.0027451171875, 0.0071739501953125, 0.008443359375, 0.0094327392578125, 0.012530517578125,
  0.0176046142578125, 0.0300162353515625, 0.0433489990234375, 0.056962646484375004,
  0.0704832763671875, 0.0770511474609375, 0.0898175048828125, 0.10311853027343751,
  0.117046142578125, 0.1312630615234375, 0.1529300537109375, 0.167607177734375,
  0.1899068603515625, 0.2124422607421875, 0.235044677734375, 0.2575535888671875,
  0.2724073486328125, 0.286978271484375, 0.3007579345703125, 0.3067425537109375,
  0.3106370849609375, 0.303756103515625, 0.2897236328125, 0.25916931152343753,
  0.2200599365234375, 0.1728209228515625, 0.133416259765625, 0.086224853515625,
  0.05493408203125, 0.02409423828125, 0.00922607421875, -0.0043409423828125, -0.0097349853515625, -0.013127685546875, -0.01423095703125, -0.013834716796875, -0.012556030273437501, -0.010675048828125, -0.00835888671875, -0.0057305908203125, -0.0000562744140625
];
```

I want to be able to make it readable using line animation like this **[`example`](http://jsfiddle.net/lachlan/YcVEA/)**

Question is now, what options do I have in React native to implement the same animation?

Thanks

Comment: You could use canvas in webview

Comment: Is it possible to do so using webview? Could you perhaps explain in more details, that would superb :)  @VilleKoo